# Will this help program my 19 button mouse?

Tags: workflow

I have a Left index finger that is fused at the second knuckle , therefore I bought a 19 button mouse to compensate. The box said it has programmable buttons.( Utechsmart Venus).  I'd like to use the 12 side button's for the combination of shift,control,alt and use the keyboard for the other characters.
Will the add-on for programming keys menus and pie help with my endeavor to continue learning blender?

Answer (score 2):

The "Programmable buttons" are usually configured in a system control panel for the device, you should find a place where you can specify what action/key is assigned to each button.

Another approach to try is to open blenders input preferences and adjust an action you want to assign to a button. Where the [mouse/key combination](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html#keymap-editor) is shown, you can click that and the next mouse or keypress will be assigned to the action. Try adjusting an action and pressing one of the mouse buttons to see if blender recognises the button, if not you will need to rely on the system configuration to set each button to emulate keystrokes.

While I am not familiar with the addon you mention, blender is very customisable, you can setup the shortcuts to suit what works for you, modifier keys can be disabled so that menus are displayed with single key presses, using python you can [create your own menus](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_menu.py) - either a vertical list of items or a [pie menu](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_pie_menu.py).

Comment: One thing to add, however, is that there might be a number of tutorials that assume Blender defaults.  For example, I came from experience with Maya, and found Blender's right-click to be awkward so I swapped it.  However, as I tried to learn Blender I found it hard to constantly swap everything so I ended up switching it back.  I know that's not an option for you but I wanted to point out that it might be challenging to mentally adjust from defaults to your mapping.  Don't give up though!  I am sure you can do it!